# Spring-boot Redis JMS JUnit

Tags: junit, redis, mockito, spring-jms, spring-boot-test

I am using Redis Server for message broker in my spring boot application.
Is there any simple way to Junit my publish and receive API?

e.g :

Publisher :

```
public String publish(Object domainObj) {

    template.convertAndSend(topic.getTopic(), domainObj.toString());
    return "Event Published";
}
```

Receiver :

public class Receiver implements MessageListener {

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] bytes) {

    System.out.println("Consumed Message {}" + message);

}
```

}

I am using `JedisConnectionFactory` and `RedisMessageListenerContainer` and `RedisTemplate` for my implementation

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName("localhost");
        configuration.setPort(6379);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> template() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("common-channel");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new Receiver());
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer() {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter(), topic());
        return container;
    }
```

Comment: No, there's no simple way you can try local-redis module..

Answer (score 1):

Unit Testing Receiver and  Publisher implementation is quite straight.
JUnit 5 coupled with Mockito extension should do the job.

For example for testing that :

```
public String publish(Object domainObj) {
    template.convertAndSend(topic.getTopic(), domainObj.toString());
    return "Event Published";
}
```

I expect that `topic` and `template` be fields of the current class.
These fields could be set by constructor.

So you could write something that check that `convertAndSend()` is eventually executed with the correct parameters :

```
@Mock 
RedisTemplate<String, Object> templateMock;

@Test
void publish(){
   Topic topicFixture = new Topic(...);
   Object domainObjFixture = new FooBar(...);
   Publisher publisher = new Publisher(templateMock, topicFixture);
   //when
   publisher.publish(domainObjFixture);
   // then
   Mockito.verify(templateMock)
          .convertAndSend(topicFixture.getTopic(), domainObjFixture);      
}
```

But I don't think that the unit test of these two classes be enough because it never tests the final things : the JMS processing performed by Redis backend.
Particularly, the `RedisConfig` part that you set with specific things as serializers that have important side effects on the processing.
For my part, I try to always write integration or partial integration tests for Redis backend stuffs to ensure a good no regression harness.

The java [embedded-redis library](https://github.com/ozimov/embedded-redis) is good for that. It allows to start a redis server
on localhost (works on Windows as well as on Linux).
Starting and stopping the redis server is as simple as :

```
RedisServer redisServer = new RedisServer(6379);
redisServer.start();
// do some work
redisServer.stop();
```

Move the `start()` in the `@BeforeEach` and the `stop()` in the `@AfterEach` and the server is ready.
Then it still requires some adjustments to ensure that the redis configuration specified in Spring is well setup during the tests while using your local redis server and not the "real" redis server. Not always simple to set but great when it is done !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to unit test this is to use `embedded-redis` module. What you do is in `BeforeAll` you can start embedded Redis and stop the embedded Redis in `AfterAll` method.

You can also `PostConstruct` `PreDestroy`  annotations to accomplish this.

If you're looking for Junit5 then you can find the code in my [repo](https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue) here

See BootstrapRedis annotation and their usage here

https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue/blob/7ef545c15985ef91ba719f070f7cc80745525047/rqueue-core/src/test/java/com/github/sonus21/rqueue/core/RedisScriptFactoryTest.java#L40